# Javascript Sort function is not consistent

Tags: javascript

I have got a list of Customers (Image1- unsorted) and displaying this list in a table.
Users able to sort this table by clicking table header.

If they click Customer Name the first time (Image2), the List is sorted by Customer Name from A-Z
Then they click the Customer Name a second time (Image3), List sorted by Customer Name from Z-A

**The issue is**, when the user clicks the Customer Name the third time (Image4), I was expecting to see the list reordered like the first time(Image 2). But it is not. The list is ordered A-Z, but it is not in the same order
As you can see from the images i attached Second Image and 3rd image orders are not the same order.

```js
if (this.orderByColSide)
   authList.sort((a, b) => a.customerCode.toLowerCase() > b.customerCode.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1);
else
   authList.sort((a, b) => a.customerCode.toLowerCase() > b.customerCode.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1);
```

[image: UnSorted]

[image: Sort by Customer]

[image: Sort Customer again]

[image: Sort Customer again]

Comment: You're not handling what happens if two things are equal.

Comment: "*when the user clicks the Customer Name the third time (Image4), I was expecting to see the list reordered like the first time(Image 2). But it is not.*" is there any such functionality in whatever you use to show you this table? It seems to toggle between sorting ascending and descending. Can it even handle removing the sorting? And how does it even work? There is not a lot to go on in this post - you're showing some sorting that will sort in ascending or descending order. No idea *what* is using nor how to remove the sort (if possible).

Comment: Hi VLAZ, thank you for answer but as you can see from image 2 and 4, they are not equl. Look at the Deal Coloumn, You can see the diffrence on Deal Coloumn

Comment: Then that's going back to my first comment - you're not handling equality.

Comment: What you mean by "not handling equality"?

Comment: Things can be equal. Things *are* equal in your case. If you have `{ firstName: "Alice", lastName: "B" }` and `{ firstName: "Alice", lastName: "A" }` then sort by first name, you will get these *in **some** order*. But without handling the case where the first names are equal, the order might be `Alice B` -> `Alice A` or vice versa. You get no real guarantee.

Comment: Sort has three states (less than, equal to, and greater than) but you only return one of two states (less than and greater than). Because of that, it's possible for the order to change when it shouldn't.

Comment: Why are you using `>` as sort comparison operator? It should never be used for sorting regardless weather you are trying to sort a number or a string. For numbers always use the `-` operator. For strings use `.localeCompare()` like `list.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))`

Comment: Thank you VLAZ, so how am i going to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi Slebetman. Do you mean                                                                                               if (this.orderByColSide){ authList.sort((a, b) => a.customerCode.localeCompare(b.customerCode));}
                        else {
                            authList.sort((a, b) => b.customerCode.localeCompare(a.customerCode)); }

Answer (score 1):

Use `localeCompare` for strings

```js
if (this.orderByColSide)
   authList.sort((a, b) => a.customerCode.toLowerCase().localCompare(b.customerCode.toLowerCase())
else
   authList.sort((a, b) => - a.customerCode.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.customerCode.toLowerCase())
```

Comment: Thank you Steven and Slebetman.  LocalCompare fixed the issue but I am not sure this is the best solution. I sort it with adding Equality into my compare, like VLAZ suggested.

Comment: The size of the integer returned from sort does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.orderByColSide)
    authList.sort((a, b) => a.customerCode.toLowerCase() > b.customerCode.toLowerCase() ? 1 : a.customerCode.toLowerCase() < b.customerCode.toLowerCase()? -1: 0);                            
 else
     authList.sort((a, b) => a.customerCode.toLowerCase() > b.customerCode.toLowerCase() ? -1 : a.customerCode.toLowerCase() < b.customerCode.toLowerCase()? 1:0);
```